# Error when pass COM interface

Tags: c#, delphi, com, interop, marshalling

Initially, it was probably not proper to create COM through late binding, and then call its methods via InvokeMember.
But now, perhaps, too late to redo everything from scratch.

Therefore, tell me how to be.

There is a COM object in the DLL. Written in Delphi7.

In C#, it is used as follows:

```
Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(ProgID, false);
object comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
// and then call methods
comType.InvokeMember("DoLongWork", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObj, null);
```

Now we need to add to it the opportunity to call the methods of the server (i.e. the one who keeps to himself this COM object)

For this, in a COM object in its TLB added additional interface

```
IHookCallback = interface(IDispatch)
 procedure ServerHook(DoStuff: integer); safecall;
end;
```

And also, in its main interface added initialization method callback

```
ITestDisp = dispinterface
...
procedure SetupHook(const Callback: IHookCallback); safecall;
```

Then imported into the VS project DLL - with this COMom inside. Thereby gained access to the interface description.

Then (in VS) created a class that implements this interface.
And I try to transfer it to the COM through InvokeMember

```
comType.InvokeMember("SetupHook", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObj, new object[] {SomeClass as IHookCallback});
```

and so, too, tried

```
comType.InvokeMember("SetupHook", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObj, new object[] {SomeClass});
```

I receive an error

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

InnerException

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I must confess that I cannot work out what you are trying to do at all. COM usually isn't this hard. Certainly opting for late binding seems like masochism.

Comment: You are right.
Everything turned out difficult. We must remake - but there is no time.
More precisely, we need to quickly fix what is there, and then it will be possible to do better.

Comment: Well, I still can't help you since I still can't work out what you did and what you are asking. Maybe somebody else can.

Comment: Hello, I ll make you a question.. you have a COM(1) in a server  that is invoqued from VS C# working good. and now you want to add a new COM(2) who uses COM(1) methods whitin the TLB?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did.
Write here may be useful to someone my decision.

Initially I have COM object with its own TLB. Written in Delphi 7.
There was also a project written in VS 2010. He created the COM using "Activator Class". And then the work was carried out through late binding. Ie through InvokeMember.

The task was this: were ready COM objects, which could not be replaced. Ie was necessary to ensure backward compatibility and work with existing code as before.

But at the same time, you had to write another 2 COM object with advanced features - support several new methods.

I solved this problem as follows: created a separate TLB on Delphi 7. It announced a completely independent interface (inherited from IDispatch but it does not matter).
Then I created a new COM object that implements the old interface and the new interface.

Then modified the C #. He also created objects through "Activator Class", but after the establishment immediately brought the created object to the second interface (I imported the description of a second TLB in C # project) with the operator "as". If the result was NULL then it was an old COM does not support the new functionality. Otherwise, we have a new COM with enhanced functionality.

Done.